# how to get this data using sql server query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Below is an image which consists of the columns `Date` and `Rate`. Based on the `Date`, it should return the rates and all corresponding dates.

[image]

The first table is my data, and the second table is what I'd like to return after querying the database. How would I write such a query?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive CTE:

```
with cte as (
      select date, rate, lead(date) over (order by date) as next_date
      from t
      union all
      select dateadd(day, 1, date), rate, next_date
      from t
      where date < next_date
     )
select date, rate
from cte
where date <> next_date;
```